# Use PyQGIS With IronPython : No module named qgis.core

Tags: python, pyqgis, c#

I need to create a Qgis python script called by IronPython for application purpose. I've already read Using PyQGIS in standalone scripts & Running application of Qgis Cookbook (https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html).

After set environment path & run my script, it gave me an error :

> IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException : 'No module named
>   qgis.core'
>
> IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException   HResult=0x80131500
>   Message=No module named qgis.core   Source=Microsoft.Dynamic
>   Arborescence des appels de procédure :    à
>   Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.LightExceptions.CheckAndThrow(Object
>   value)    à
>   IronPython.Runtime.Operations.PythonOps.ImportStar(CodeContext
>   context, String fullName, Int32 level)    à
>   Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`3.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)    à
>   Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)    à
>   Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run2[T0,T1,TRet](T0 arg0,
>   T1 arg1)    à
>   IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.RunWorker(CodeContext ctx)    à
>   IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.Run(Scope scope)    à
>   IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget(Scope scope)    à
>   IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.Run(Scope scope)    à
>   Microsoft.Scripting.SourceUnit.Execute(Scope scope, ErrorSink
>   errorSink)    à
>   Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptSource.Execute(ScriptScope scope)
>   à Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine.ExecuteFile(String path,
>   ScriptScope scope)    à
>   LivrableChecker.Checker.FileDepencyChecker.QGISChecker() dans
>   C:\Users\BVCS5568\Desktop\Livrable Checker\3 - Source
>   code\LivrableChecker\LivrableChecker\Core\Checker\FileDepencyChecker.cs
>   :ligne 141    à ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args) dans
>   C:\Users\BVCS5568\Desktop\Livrable Checker\3 - Source
>   code\LivrableChecker\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs :ligne 71

Utilities: Ironpython 2.7, Qgis 3.0, Visual Studio

Here is my code For C# call and Python script:

https://pastebin.com/FpnncwSj